# Unable to adopt SD card as internal storage on my j7 prime with android marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-galaxy-j7

I recently upgraded to 6.0.1 Marshmallow on my Galaxy J7 Prime and I would like to adopt an SD card as internal storage. but it doesnt give me an option to this

I formatted the SD card, there is no "Internal" option, only a "Portable" option.

Comment: Samsung has that option disabled in all of it's phones, like many manufacturers, because it turned out to be terrible and caused all kinds of data loss due to SD cards not being able to handle the exponential increase in read/write operations, leading to catastrophic data loss... In encrypted storage if a single bit is incorrect in the wrong spot all information on that card is permanently unrecoverable.

Comment: @acejavelin It's not actually disabled, there is just not in GUI option for that. Adoptable storage is Android feature and like that can't be disabled by OEM's.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I understand that... but I still don't recommend using adopted storage, I have seen more failures than successes over time it seems like. Even with high quality SD cards, it seems to just destroy them and at random with no warning and due the encryption typically no data is recoverable at all.

Comment: @acejavelin Yeah I know that it killed my few cards r/w speeds, fortunately didn't lose any data. However I think every user with 8GB phone is forced to use adoptable storage in my case I wouldn't be able to install half of apps I have and couldn't download much because it goes to internal storage by default, fortunately there is less and less 8GB phones

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје So what should I do? I only have 16gb memory thats already filled and I have 64gb of external storage lying there. I have tried moving the apps that can be moved to the Sd card

Comment: @acejavelin So what should I do? I only have 16gb memory thats already filled and I have 64gb of external storage lying there. I have moved the apps that can be moved to the Sd card but the still have to delete some apps. its so frustrating. to thing that I switched from a phono with 32gb internal storage to this.

Comment: I didn't say don't do that, if you need more storage for apps than you adopt it, but keep in mind that storage will be encrypted. However if storage is needed for photos and such media then simply move media to SD card. Also make sure that your SD card is at least class 10 or UHC I.

Answer (score 5):

Most of OEM's doesn't offer in gui option for adoptable storage. So you have to do it via ADB. Here is how [click](http://www.modaco.com/news/android/heres-how-to-configure-adoptable-storage-on-your-s7-s7-edge-r1632/)

Here it is:
NOTE  all data on your SD card will be lost.

1. Make sure USB debugging is enabled in developer options under settings and then connect your phone to PC via USB cable.
2. Open terminal or command line on PC ( make sure you have ADB installed if not then download minimal ADB and fastboot, you can find it on Google [click](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) ) type command "**adb devices**" to make sure phone is detected, then type "**adb shell**"
   3.Type '**sm list-disks**' to list the disks available, the result should be something like "*disk:179:160*"
3. To make SD adoptable use command "**sm partition disk:xxx:xxx private**" where *xxx:xxx* is replaced with result from previous command, in some cases there is **_** instead of **:** so watch out for that. If you want to use only half of SD as adoptable then use this command "**sm partition disk:xxx:xxx mixed 50**" and that's it.

If you want to move your data (pictures, videos etc) you can go to settings>storage>SD card>more and you will have there option "migrate data" hit it and let it go.