# Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '1636 volume partition disk:179:64 private' failed with '400 1636 Command failed'

Tags: adb

using the method described  [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180306/unable-to-adopt-sd-card-as-internal-storage-on-my-j7-prime-with-android-marshmal).

First command

> adb devices

Output of first command

> List of devices attached
>   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>   * daemon started successfully
>   26EBB18827208648        device

Second command

> adb shell

third command

> sm list-disks

Output of third command

> disk:179:64

when I enter the last command

> sm partition disk:179:64 private

last command output

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '1636 volume partition disk:179:64 private' failed with '400 1636 Command failed'

if I try to enter this command instead of the last command

> sm partition disk:179:64 mixed 50

still an error shows up

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '1637 volume partition disk:179:64 mixed 50' failed with '400 1637 Command failed'

Phone:Huawei 7y prime

Any way to solve this?

Comment: Did you enter `xxx:xxx` literally or use the value from the 2nd step? Could you [edit] and provide the exact commands and their output?

Comment: Edited the question, i thought that it will be a security risk if i share those piecies of information.

Comment: Are you really sure you should try your hand at repartitioning phones, if you don't know how `vold` works?

Comment: @Death Mask Salesman what do you mean?